# OpenID : Discovery Exception : org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisException: 0x706: GET failed 503:HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: openid, tomcat6

I build the `OpenID` server for Internal use based on Google OpenID `OpenID4Java`.

I deployed it on `Apache-Tomcat 6.0`.

When consumer is trying to discover, It's throwing follwoing error

```
org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisException: 0x706: GET failed on http://localhost:9090/idp4java/idp : 503:HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable
    at org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.retrieveXrdsLocation(YadisResolver.java:371)
    at org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.discover(YadisResolver.java:233)
    at org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.discover(YadisResolver.java:221)
```

When I am accessing the `XRDS` by url http://localhost:9090/idp4java/idp I am getting it but when my consumer code trying to get it then above error is coming.

Do we need to do any setting on `Tomcat` to enable `Yadis`?

Any Idea why this might be happening. My code is working fine with `Google IDP`.

Thanks in Advance.
Jha

Answer (score 0):

Last Friday did some reserach on this and could resolved it.

Today morning put the logger level to debug to see what's going on and found that the HTTP Error 503 was coming due to Proxy setting in the code.

In the Production scnenario you will need the Proxy setting so that OpenID can be connected.You appserver/webserver need to connect directly to OpenID for Discovery and Association process.

HttpClientFactory.setProxyProperties(proxySettings);

HttpClientFactory class is from OpenID4Java.

After commenting the above line I start getting the 404 Error.

Reason for that was "/" at the End of OpenIDURL i.e. http://myopenid.net/idp/. When I removed this "/" it start working.

Thanks
Jha